# ACM: Web Navigation

Tags: c++

Note:This problem I wrote is just for the people who know about ACM questions.
I have problem with this question. I wrote a good solution for this but every time I send it I get Wrong Answer. I don't know what's wrong here. I test this code for lots of test cases. Can you help me to fix my code?
Here is the link of the question: http://sharecode.ir/section/problemset/problem/1022.
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--)
    {
        string page[1000] = { "" };
        int cntr = 0;
        page[cntr] = "http://www.acm.org/";
        string page1;
        while (1)
        {
            cin >> page1;
            if (page1 == "QUIT")
                break;
            if (page1 == "VISIT")
            {
                cntr++;
                cin >> page1;
                page[cntr] = page1;
                cout << page1 << endl;
            }
            if (page1 == "BACK")
            {
                cntr--;
                if (cntr >= 0)
                    cout << page[cntr] << endl;
                else
                {
                    cout << "Ignored" << endl;
                    cntr = 0;
                }
            }
            if (page1 == "FORWARD")
            {
                cntr++;
                if (page[cntr] == "")
                    cout << "Ignored" << endl;
                else
                    cout << page[cntr] << endl;
            }
        }
        if (n) cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't clear *forwards* after visiting a site. That's why you get wrong answer.

Here is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int n){
    cin >> n;
    while (n--){
        string c;
        vector <string> a(999,"\0");
        a[0] = "http://www.acm.org/";
        int i = 0;
        while(cin>>c,c != "QUIT"){
            if (c == "VISIT"){
                i++;
                string s;
                cin >> s;
                a[i] = s;
                cout << a[i] << "\n";
                int t = i+1;
                while (a[t] != "\0") {
                    a[t] = "\0";
                    t++;
                }

            }
            if (c == "BACK"){
                i--;
                if (i < 0) {cout << "Ignored\n"; i=0;} else cout << a[i] << "\n";
            }
            if (c == "FORWARD"){
                i++;
                if (a[i] == "\0") {cout << "Ignored\n"; i--;} else cout << a[i] << "\n"; 
            }
        }
        if (n) cout << "\n";
    }

}
```